# Ionic toast scss class - Angular - android

Tags: android, angular, sass, toast, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5, Angular and cordova. I have a service provider with a global toast method, code below:

```
 GlobalToast(text: string) {
    // creating a toast for global use throughout the app
    this.toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: text,
      cssClass: 'my-toast-class',
      animated: true,
      duration: 370}).then((toastData) => {
        toastData.present();
      });
  }
```

I am calling the toast in different components, as below:

```
this.newFavAppService.GlobalToast(this.translate.instant('Favourites.Added'));
this.newFavAppService.GlobalToast(this.translate.instant('Favourites.Removed'));
```

My scss is set in the global.scss file, code below:

```
.md{ 
    .my-toast-class{
        --background: #000534 !important;
        --color: white !important;
        --width: max-content !important;
        --height: 45px !important;
        --border-radius: 200px !important;
        position: sticky !important;
        margin-bottom:12% !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        opacity: 87% !important;
        top: 100% !important;
    }
}
.ios{ 
    .my-toast-class{
        --background: #000534;
        --color: white;
        --width: max-content;
        --height: 45px;
        --border-radius: 200px;
        position: sticky;
        margin-bottom:10%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0.83;
        top: 100%;
    }
}
```

The toast work on ios (both release and debug build) and works on android debug build only. Once i build the app for release on android the toast doesnt show up anymore. Might I also add that if i remove the code in the global.scss class the toast works with the basic scss it is given in the beginning. I think this shows something is wrong with the global.scss file when i build for release in android.

Does anyone have a solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but what I did was put:

```
@media screen {
  ion-toast.toast-custom-class {
    --border-radius: 30px !important;
    --text-align: center !important;
    --background-color: #676767 !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

at the bottom of my global.scss file. So far it works for me on Android and web, not sure about IOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public toastCtrl:ToastController) {}

async openToast() {  
  const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({  
    message: 'LeaveType was Selected Successfully',
    // position: 'middle',  
    duration: 3000  
  });  
  toast.present();  
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.